# Renaming a subset of names

Tags: r, dataframe

Lets say I'm trying to rename a some of the variables in data frame.

```
>dat = data.frame(var1 = 1:10, var2 = letters[1:10], var3 = LETTERS[1:10])  
>names(dat[,1:2]) = c("VAR_1", "VAR_2")  
>names(dat)
```

returns

```
>[1] "var1" "var2" "var3
```

while

```
>names(dat)[1:2] = c("VAR_1", "VAR_2") 
>name(dat)
```

successfully renames the columns.

```
> [1] "VAR_1" "VAR_2" "var3"
```

Why is it that the second method works, but the first one fails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`dat[,1:2]` is a subsetted copy of `dat`, not the original. So you modify the names of this copy in the first example, and the copy is immediately discarded, with the original being unchanged.

Comment: That's what I was suspecting, but how is that you can modify the contents of a data frame via subsetting? That is, why does dat[,1] <- 2:11 change the original data frame?

Comment: Because `[<-` is a separate function to support this. Note there is also a `names<-` function.

Comment: @Nathan Somewhat mind-bendingly, compare `"names<-"(dat,"[<-"(names(dat),c(1,2),c("VAR_1", "VAR_2")))` with `"names<-"("["(dat,,c(1,2)),c("VAR_1", "VAR_2"))`.